# Как убрать вертикальные пробелы в консоли?

Tags: visual-c++, консоль

делаю игру на С++ в консоли, проблема в этих пробелах.
[image: Пример пробелов]

Из-за них змейка визуально быстрее двигается, да и они не выглядят красиво. Можно их как то убрать, или уменьшить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [псевдографику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), а не решётки.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

Ставим шрифт *Lucida Console* и галочку жирный. Визуально довольно хорошо. Но псевдографика выглядит круче. Выбор за вами.